# node.js not responding from intranet

Tags: node.js, arduino

I have the following node.js server defined and running

```
var httpServer = http.createServer(onRequest).listen(8080,'0.0.0.0',function(){
    console.log("Listening at: http://192.168.1.6:8080/");
    console.log("Server is up");
}); 
serialListener(debug);
initSocketIO(httpServer,debug);
```

I can see my page from my intranet. But there is no accessibility from the internet. I have port forwarded 8080 and have tested it using WAMP server.

Can anyone help me please. 
Also there is a funny thing - The node.js server is running , but the web page is accessible only when there is a internet connection available. Why is this so?

Answer (score 0):

If you can see it at all, then your node is working properly. If there's places you can't see it from, it's probably a firewall issue, either on your box or on a switch in front of your box.

Comment: I have stopped all the firewall. But there is no result. Moreover , the same port is working fine with WAMP server.

Answer (score 0):

Check your proxy settings if any (Tools-->Internet Options-->Connections-->LAN Settings in IE8, don't have any other browsers available to me right now), there may be more to it than just a firewall. If your company uses a configuration script then this can override the setting to ignore local addresses (at least in IE8).

Comment: There is nothing in the LAN settings. Moreover I am using Digisol Router in my house. I am talking of my house .